# Loop in assembly doesn't work

Tags: assembly

I had some problems when I tried to create a loop in asm.
So I created another code with just the loop.
The problem is, when I decrement or increment the `ecx`, the variable gets messed.
If I use the loop instruction without the dec it doesn't work either.
How do I use the `ecx` to loop?

Code

```
section .text
     global main

     extern printf
section .data
FORMAT: db "L", 10, 0 ; just to print the L 10 times
main:

     mov ecx, 10 ; start the counter in 10
     jmp runloop ; i imagine i dont need it
runloop:
     push FORMAT
     call printf
     add esp, 4
     dec ecx
     cmp ecx, 0
     jne runloop
```

Comment: You're right, `jmp runloop` is of no use there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ecx` value is not guaranteed to be preserved across the `printf` call. Use one of the following registers instead: `ebx`, `ebp`, `esi`, `edi`. You should preserve them too by `push`ing the register of choise onto the stack and restoring it afterwards.